# How to pass None to dictionary without initialising

Tags: python, dictionary

- I have a parent dictionary my_d
- If no value is found i need to pass None
- My code is working perfectly fine
  Below is the code

```
    event =  {
              "id": "12",
              "name": Abc,
              "redacted": false
            }
    my_d = {'id': None, 'name': None, 'description': None}
    my_d['id'] = event['id']
    my_d['name'] = event['name']
    my_d['description'] = event['description']
```

Is there any way to re write the above code

like below

```
my_d['id'] = if event['id'] else None
my_d['name'] = if event['name']  else None
my_d['description'] = if  event['description'] else None
```

Basically i dont want to use `my_d = {'id': None, 'name': None, 'description': None}`

I just shown one sample dictionary, I need to loop so many event

Comment: [`dict.fromkeys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my_d = dict((k, event.get(k)) for k in ["id", "name", "description"])
```

Comment: `event[k] if k in event else None` can be written more simply as `event.get(k)`

Comment: It would be slightly faster if you will use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) instead of [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list). Also *using [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dict)* should be faster than *passing generator to [`dict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict)*.